# Error 404 for some values of get parameters

Tags: apache, url

I am working on a website with one of the script referred as:

```
http://localhost/query.php?lat=1.361109&lng=103.828969&rad=2 [404]
```

I am getting `404 Not found` error for this URL, while at the same time for a slightly different value of one of the parameter the script is accessible and is being executed. e.g.

```
http://localhost/query.php?lat=1.361119&lng=103.828969&rad=2  [Working fine]
```

I am using Apache 2.4 on Windows. Can anyone point out what could possibly be the reason for this? I am not using `.htaccess` anywhere in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the server side code checks the data and return 404 in some cases like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage<Book> GetBook(int id)
{
HttpResponseMessage<Book> result;
var book  = _repo.GetBook(id);
if (book != null)
{
    result = new HttpResponseMessage<Book>(book);
}
else
{
  // 404 error 
    result = new HttpResponseMessage<Book>(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}
return result;
```

}

Comment: I didn't mention it in the question but I am using PHP. I am not redirecting to any 404 page at all.

Comment: are you checking the input coming from Get request?